# Warning: require(/home/domain/public_html/domainname.com/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: wordpress

Warning: require(/home/domain/public_html/domainname.com/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/domain/public_html/domainname.com/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/domaine/public_html/domainname.com/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/domain/public_html/domainname.com/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

So I have seen this error before once and it actually occurred on this domain prior to today, but I was able to temporarily resolve this by updating Wordpress 4.9.5 from 4.9.4. This has never happened to me on my host with any other site and I have set up dozens over the years with different Wordpress versions.

However, it just started giving me this error again today only on wp-admin/index.php. If I access any other page, like wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page, the page loads fine.

I have not made any changes to my site aside from adding content and products between last night and today when the error first came up. Disabling all plugins does not fix the issue. There's no error log yet because the site has no errors, it just won't load /wp-admin.

What is going on? I'm happy to provide the real domain name to those who might have an idea.

Comment: It seems to mean that the file is missing.  Is the file there?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. `wp-blog-header.php` does not belong to `wp-admin` directory. This is a virus. I had to download the whole Website and then cleaned with antivirus.